# Error code from running Heckit method

Tags: r, regression, truncation

I tried using the Heckit method for sample selection correction. After I ran the model I received the error message.

```
Warning message:
In sqrt(diag(vcov(object, part = "full"))) : NaNs produced
```

What does this mean and how do I address it?

Comment: `NaN` means "Not a Number". What is `object` here?

Comment: @jsb How do I find out what the object is? Sorry I'm new to all of this.

Comment: Can you update your question with your code?